Problema con animaciones de Lottie en Flutter
estoy desarrollando una app en visual studio usando Flutter, y al implementar la animación con lottie todo es correcto y en principio se implementa bien, sin embargo, en caso de que la animación contenga formas circulares o curvas, estás se deforman y aparecen con forma de "flor", no se porque y me estoy desesperando. He probado a cambiar el tamaño, el contenendor, añadir rutas de fusión y nada. Aquí dejo el código y una imagen de la animación, aunque repito, ocurre en todas. Muchas gracias a todos, decir que es la primera vez que utilizo Flutter.
class LottieAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  const LottieAnimation({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Lottie.asset(
        'assets/lottie/login.json',
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    );
  }
}


name: travel_buddy
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  lottie: ^3.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/background.jpg
    - assets/lottie/login.json


Eso es un problema del formato del Json que descargaste. Por ejemplo si usas la pagina Lottie Files prueba usar el Asset Link del Json en ves de usar el Json descargado. Ejemplo:


  class LottiePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const LottiePage({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Lottie.network(
              'https://lottie.host/f93be090-3e8f-4bb5-b3d7-d18a2319f90b/sOrLuofDUo.json',
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }



